Mypy doesn't detect a type guard, why?
I am trying to teach myself how to use type guards in my new Python project in combination with pydantic-settings, and mypy doesn't seem to pick up on them. What am I doing wrong here?
Code:
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler
from functools import lru_cache
from typing import Final, Literal, TypeGuard

from pydantic import EmailStr, SecretStr
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict

SMTP_PORT: Final = 587


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    """
    Please make sure your .env contains the following variables:
    - BOT_TOKEN - an API token for your bot.
    - TOPIC_ID - an ID for your group chat topic.
    - GROUP_CHAT_ID - an ID for your group chat.
    - ENVIRONMENT - if you intend on running this script on a VPS, this improves logging
        information in your production system.

    Required only in production:

    - SMTP_HOST - SMTP server address (e.g., smtp.gmail.com)
    - SMTP_USER - Email username/address for SMTP authentication
    - SMTP_PASSWORD - Email password or app-specific password
    """

    ENVIRONMENT: Literal["production", "development"]

    # Telegram bot configuration
    BOT_TOKEN: SecretStr
    TOPIC_ID: int
    GROUP_CHAT_ID: int

    # Email configuration
    SMTP_HOST: str | None = None
    SMTP_USER: EmailStr | None = None
    # If you're using Gmail, this needs to be an app password
    SMTP_PASSWORD: SecretStr | None = None

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file="../.env", env_file_encoding="utf-8")


@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def get_settings() -> Settings:
    """This needs to be lazily evaluated, otherwise pytest gets a circular import."""
    return Settings()


type DotEnvStrings = str | SecretStr | EmailStr


def is_all_email_settings_provided(
    host: DotEnvStrings | None,
    user: DotEnvStrings | None,
    password: DotEnvStrings | None,
) -> TypeGuard[DotEnvStrings]:
    """
    Type guard that checks if all email settings are provided.

    Returns:
        True if all email settings are provided as strings, False otherwise.
    """
    return all(isinstance(x, (str, SecretStr, EmailStr)) for x in (host, user, password))


def get_logger():
    ...
    settings = get_settings()
    if settings.ENVIRONMENT == "development":
        level = logging.INFO
    else:
        # # We only email logging information on failure in production.
        if not is_all_email_settings_provided(
            settings.SMTP_HOST, settings.SMTP_USER, settings.SMTP_PASSWORD
        ):
            raise ValueError("All email environment variables are required in production.")
        level = logging.ERROR
        email_handler = SMTPHandler(
            mailhost=(settings.SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT),
            fromaddr=settings.SMTP_USER,
            toaddrs=settings.SMTP_USER,
            subject="Application Error",
            credentials=(settings.SMTP_USER, settings.SMTP_PASSWORD.get_secret_value()),
            # This enables TLS - https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler
            secure=(),
        )

And here is what mypy is saying:
media_only_topic\media_only_topic.py:122: error: Argument "mailhost" to "SMTPHandler" has incompatible type "tuple[str | SecretStr, int]"; expected "str | tuple[str, int]"  [arg-type]
media_only_topic\media_only_topic.py:123: error: Argument "fromaddr" to "SMTPHandler" has incompatible type "str | None"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
media_only_topic\media_only_topic.py:124: error: Argument "toaddrs" to "SMTPHandler" has incompatible type "str | None"; expected "str | list[str]"  [arg-type]
media_only_topic\media_only_topic.py:126: error: Argument "credentials" to "SMTPHandler" has incompatible type "tuple[str | None, str | Any]"; expected "tuple[str, str] | None"  [arg-type]
media_only_topic\media_only_topic.py:126: error: Item "None" of "SecretStr | None" has no attribute "get_secret_value"  [union-attr]
Found 5 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

I would expect mypy here to read up correctly that my variables can't even in theory be None, but type guards seem to change nothing here, no matter how many times I change the code here. Changing to Pyright doesn't make a difference. What would be the right approach here?

TypeGuard applies to the first argument (second in methods so it doesn't look at self), not to all of them. You can't spell "a helper to assert that all variables are not None" in python's static typing AFAIC.

Make a separate ProdSettings class. ProdSettings will raise an error if any of those values are missing.
class ProdSettings(BaseSettings):   
    ENVIRONMENT: Literal["production"]
    
    BOT_TOKEN: SecretStr
    TOPIC_ID: int
    GROUP_CHAT_ID: int

    SMTP_HOST: str
    SMTP_USER: EmailStr
    SMTP_PASSWORD: SecretStr

    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(env_file="../.env", env_file_encoding="utf-8")

Change Settings to DevSettings and overwrite ProdSettings to allow for None in development.
class DevSettings(ProdSettings):
    ENVIRONMENT: Literal["development"]

    SMTP_HOST: str | None = None
    SMTP_USER: EmailStr | None = None
    SMTP_PASSWORD: SecretStr | None = None

Use a Discriminator to declare a Settings type, while asserting what makes them different.
type Settings = Annotated[DevSettings | ProdSettings, Field(discriminator="ENVIRONMENT")]

When you run get_settings, try dev first, then prod. Set the return type as Settings.
@lru_cache(maxsize=1)
def get_settings() -> Settings: # Alternatively, you could directly put `Annotated[DevSettings | ProdSettings, Field(discriminator="ENVIRONMENT")]` here.
    """This needs to be lazily evaluated, otherwise pytest gets a circular import."""
    try:
        return DevSettings()
    except ValidationError:
        return ProdSettings()

Now when you have if settings.ENVIRONMENT == "development": this acts as a TypeGuard (You could do this explicitly as well). You'll see that mypy recognizes true as meaning settings is an instance of DevSettings and otherwise an instance of ProdSettings.
def get_logger():
    settings = get_settings()
    if settings.ENVIRONMENT == "development":
        level = logging.INFO
    else:
        level = logging.ERROR
        email_handler = SMTPHandler(
            mailhost=(settings.SMTP_HOST, SMTP_PORT),
            fromaddr=settings.SMTP_USER,
            toaddrs=settings.SMTP_USER,
            subject="Application Error",
            credentials=(settings.SMTP_USER, settings.SMTP_PASSWORD.get_secret_value()),
            # This enables TLS - https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler
            secure=(),
        )


A discriminator was the missing key piece in my head, thanks!
